# ID of the longest string in "group by"

Tags: mysql

How do I get the id of MAX(name)?  The id I get from below query doesn't correspond to the row where MAX(name) is in.

```
SELECT id, MAX(name) from table group by country

id    name        country
+---+-----------+---------+
| 1 | John      | USA     |   
+---+-----------+---------+
| 2 | Joe       | CHINA   |   
+---+-----------+---------+
| 3 | Jonah     | USA     |   
+---+-----------+---------+
| 4 | Jonathan  | USA     |   
+---+-----------+---------+
```

Edit:
The purpose is to get the longest name in every country. So from the table, I'd like to see the result to be id 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with variables, and self joins, and depending on your version of sql window functions, but you can also do some string manipulation.

```
SELECT country, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(ids, ',', 1) AS id
FROM (
    SELECT country, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY LENGTH(NAME) DESC) AS ids
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY country
) z
```

Also, max(name) won't get you the one with the longest name, it will get you the one closest to the end of the alphabet.

You can also try (assuming you need to account for the possibility of more than one name per country having the same max length):

```
SELECT z.country, z.id
FROM table z
JOIN (  
    SELECT country, MAX(LENGTH(name)) AS maxLen
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY country
) lens ON (lens.country = z.country AND lens.maxLen = LENGTH(z.name))
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's CHAR_LENGTH

Comment: Great! The second one is exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT id, country
FROM table
WHERE (country, CHAR_LENGTH(name)) IN (SELECT country, MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(name)) 
                                       FROM table
                                       GROUP BY country)
GROUP BY country
```

Note, however, that there may be more than one row returned if there are more than one records having this length of the name!

Comment: This doesn't get the longest name in each country.